# Invalid argument error when accessing URL

Tags: python, html, google-chrome, web-scraping

I´m new at webscraping. I´ve just downloaded the chromedriver: `Current stable release: ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106.`

Now, I was starting to code but when trying to access the URL I want I get an error. Please, see the code below and the error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

#Set path to chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe')

#Open the URL where I will perform the webscraping
driver.get("< a href=https://www.pccomponentes.com/portatiles")
```

The error displayed is the following one:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)
```

My Chrome version is: Versión 80.0.3987.149 (Build oficial) (64 bits).

Answer (score 1):

call to

```
driver.get("< a href=https://www.pccomponentes.com/portatiles")
```

is not a valid URL. It must be `https://www.pccomponentes.com/portatiles` like

```
driver.get("https://www.pccomponentes.com/portatiles")
```